# BB companion for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, integration, webbbs

I'm looking for a bulletin-board software that will integrate with wordpress so that I can get peer-review on draft pages, powerpoints, other files

Comment: Possibly better of on the Wordpress SE site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might take a look at [this blog post](http://webitect.net/blogging/create-a-community-blog-with-10-wordpress-plugins/).  its about community blogging, and has plugins that are made to help that.  #8 is a message board, but it hasn't been updated in a while, so i'm not sure if it will work with wp3.